# Problem in deriving faraday's law using only basic principles (coloumb's law , special relativity, charge invariance, suoerposition)

Tags: electromagnetism, maxwell-equations

classical electromagnetism , from my understanding can be derived completely from coloumb's law , charge invariance, superposition principle and postulates of special relativity. Biot savart law and lorentz force law are all consequences of it .                         For derieving faraday's we need not do any experiments,  flux rule : e=-d(phi)/dt  (e is induced emf and phi is magnetic flux) can be proved from motional emf . From flux rule , it can be understood that emf is induced when area of conducting loop changes in constant magnetic field or magnetic feild is a function of time with constant area. As the flux rule rule is derived from no experimental information other than lorentz force law  biot savart law ,we should be able to prove that changing magnetic feild induces emf and hence current is induced . It seems that magnetic feild cannot induce current because it acts on moving charges (which in our case is not moving).experiments shows that it is non conservative electric feild that induces current , but why do we need to do experiment because we already proved it in flux rule.                                      **My question is that this information of inducing emf was in flux rule , but it seems that we can not prove induced non conservative electric feild from  basic priciples** (coloumb's law , special

relativity,charge invariance....)

Comment: Your question could be vastly improved with paragraph breaks and consolidation of the argument. But I think your idea is not going to work for the following reason: we know so much of the theory that we know how much can be removed. Between Maxwell's equations and the Abraham-Lorentz force law, you can at most remove one equation, and arrive at it from imposing consistency. So, any attempts to derive from something more fundamental is incredibly likely to fail. In particular, Coulomb and Biot-Savart are much less nice to assume than Maxwell's equations.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question. I simply try to show you on a simple example that a conservative field in a frame can no longer be in another frame.

In some inertial frame, take the permanent very simple electromagnetic field : $$\vec{E}=A(x \vec{e_y}+y
 \vec{e_x})$$ $$\vec{B}=\vec{0}$$

You can easily check that $\vec{\nabla} \times \vec{E}=\vec{0}$

Now, transform the field in a new frame : $$x=\gamma (x'+vt')$$
The transformation laws are :
$$\vec{E'_{\parallel}}=\vec{E_{\parallel}}=Ay
 \vec{e_x}=y'
 \vec{e_x}$$
$$\vec{E'_{\perp}}=\gamma(\vec{E_{\perp}}+\vec{v}\times \vec{B})=\gamma \vec{E_{\perp}}=\gamma A x \vec{e_y}= \gamma^2 A (x'+vt') \vec{e_y} $$
$$\vec{B'_{\parallel}}=\vec{B_{\parallel}}=\vec{0}$$
$$\vec{B'_{\perp}}=\gamma(\vec{B_{\perp}}-(1/c^2)\vec{v}\times \vec{E})=-(\gamma/c^2)(\vec{v}\times \vec{E})=-A(\gamma/c^2)vx \vec{e_y}$$

So, using this transformations rules, you'll find :
$$\vec{E'}=A(y'\vec{e_x}+\gamma^2 (x'+vt') \vec{e_y})$$ $$\vec{B'}=-A(\gamma^2/c^2)v(x'+vt') \vec{e_z}$$
In the new frame, the electric field is non conservative : $$\vec{\nabla} \times \vec{E'}=A(\gamma^2-1)\vec{e_z}$$
And $$\frac{\partial \vec{B'}}{\partial t'}=-A(\gamma^2 v^2/c^2)v\vec{e_z}$$

But $(\gamma^2-1)=\gamma^2(1-1/\gamma^2)=\gamma^2 v^2/c^2$. So, as expected :
$$\vec{\nabla} \times \vec{E'}=-\frac{\partial \vec{B'}}{\partial t'}$$

The Faraday law is simply the integral form of the Maxwell-Faraday equation and is clearly true in the new frame.

Hope it can help and sorry for my poor english.